# Install newer vagrant on Ubuntu LTS 14.04 (1.5+ ideally) for Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead, apt

With an `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade vagrant`, Ubuntu tells me I'm at the newest version, `1.4.3`. This older version is not working properly when trying to setup Laravel Homestead, whose [documentation for Laravel 5.0](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead#installation-and-setup) states:

> If this fails, you may have an older version of vagrant that requires
>   the url of the box. The following should work:
>
> vagrant box add laravel/homestead
>   https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead

Which results in:

```
❯ vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
Downloading box from URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
Extracting box...e: 0/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
file you're trying to add is not corrupted and try again. The
output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

bsdtar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

[The documentation for 5.1+](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#installation-and-setup) states:

> If this command fails, make sure your Vagrant installation is up to date.

and omits the alternative with the full URL to the box entirely.

How can I update my Vagrant install to the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly download vagrant from https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html for the OS you need (should be https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.8.1/vagrant_1.8.1_x86_64.deb), and then `sudo dpkg -i vagrant_1.8.1_x86_64.deb`

Comment: Ok, how simple, I just wasn't sure if there was a 'best practice' method of adding repositories or what not.

Comment: well there's no ppa as far as I know so ... to upgrade to the latest version you better download from site for vagrant